# How to update nested protobuf field

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm using protobuf 3.14 in Go, trying to update some nested field, but it causes panic:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x30 pc=0x670028]
```

The .proto file:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
option go_package = ".;my";

message My {
    message _struct {
        bytes Data = 1;
    }

    _struct Struct = 2; // e
}
```

The go code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "aj/my"
)

func main() {
    m := my.My{}
    m.Struct.Data = []byte{1, 2, 3} // this causes panic, how to set it correctly?
}
```

I need to modify the value, but I don't see any *setter* in *.pb.go*, how to modify it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `m.Struct` is just a pointer to `_struct` type and it's not initialized yet, so you can't assign anything to it's `Data` Field.

If you look at the generated code for `My` message, it's something like this:

```
type My struct {
    state         protoimpl.MessageState
    sizeCache     protoimpl.SizeCache
    unknownFields protoimpl.UnknownFields

    Struct *My_XStruct
}
```

so `Struct` type is pointer to `My_XStruct`. You have to do something like this:

```
m := my.My{}
m.Struct = &my.My_XStruct{}
m.Struct.Data = []byte{1, 2}
```